This method does I/O on the main thread underneath that can lead to UI responsiveness issues when called on main thread
This same line of code a week ago was not causing any problems. Then suddenly when trying to build yesterday I get this error:

{"message":"This method does I/O on the main thread underneath that can lead to UI responsiveness issues when called on main thread. Consider ways to optimize this code path","antipattern trigger":"-[NSData initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:]","message type":"suppressable","show in console":"0"}

Any ideas on how to fix this?
Here's the code it's complaining about:
if let retrievedTokenData = try? Data(contentsOf: Token.archiveURL), let decodedTokenList = try? propertyListDecoder.decode(Array<Token>.self, from: retrievedTokenData)

which is part of this:
static func loadFromFile() -> [Token] {
        let propertyListDecoder = PropertyListDecoder()
        if let retrievedTokenData = try? Data(contentsOf: Token.archiveURL), let decodedTokenList = try? propertyListDecoder.decode(Array<Token>.self, from: retrievedTokenData) {
            
            return decodedTokenList
        } else {
            return []
        }
    }

I tried amending this code with guard statements with no change in the error:
static func loadFromFile() -> [Token] {
        let propertyListDecoder = PropertyListDecoder()
        
        guard let retrievedTokenData = try? Data(contentsOf: Token.archiveURL) else { return [] }
        guard let decodedTokenList = try? propertyListDecoder.decode(Array<Token>.self, from: retrievedTokenData) else { return [] }
        
            return decodedTokenList
    }

I'm running Xcode 15.3 and iOS 17.

Can you check initWithContentsOfURL? You are using try? Data(contentsOf: Token.archiveURL). According to the link This method runs synchronously and blocks the calling thread until it finishes, don’t invoke it from the main thread. Use file coordination or one of the nonblocking file-related APIs instead. Is this function loadFromFilecalling from the main thread in some cases?

Yes I am calling it from the main thread. However the problem has resolved itself. It's unclear exactly why.
